# split method java

Tags: java, split

I would like to know the regex for removing the period from a string without affecting the decimal number and then store them as separate tokens

```
str = "..A 546.88 end."
```

in the above string value I just need only the values "546.88", "A", "end" and store them into an array

thanks for help

Comment: I would consider splitting on the space and then cleaning up the split tokens ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: i've already tried splitting them but when i start to include splitting the periods, it also deletes the decimal point from 546.88 which is not what i want. what i want is an array containing "A", "546.88", "end" if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most generic would be:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

I created a small sample to do what you ask in your comment:

> what i want is an array containing "A", "546.88", "end" if it's possible

```
public class JavaApplication39 {

    static String str = "..A 546.88 end.";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a pattern to match breaks
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?");
        // Split input with the pattern
        String[] result = p.split(str);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        while (m.find()) {//all those that match
            strings.add(m.group());
            //System.out.println(m.group());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {//all those that dont match
            strings.add(result[i].replaceAll("\\.", "").trim());//strip '.' and ' '
            // System.out.println(result[i]);
        }
        //all contents in array
        for (Iterator<String> it = strings.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String string = it.next();
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good expnaination +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two questions. The first is removing all periods which aren't part of a decimal number, which you can do by preserving the two groups from the following regex:

```
"(.*(\\D|^))\\.+((\\D|$).*)"
```

This regex is: Anything - Not digit or start of line - Period - Not digit or end of line - Anything

```
String s = "..A 546.88 .end.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*(\\D|^))\\.+((\\D|$).*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.matches())
{
    s = m.group(1) + "" + m.group(3);
    System.out.println(s);
    m = p.matcher(s);
}
```

Gives

```
A 546.88 end
```

The second problem is getting the three values out of the remaining string, for which you can just use `myString.split("\\s+")` - which gives you the three values in an array.

```
String[] myArray = s.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: thanks. but i've got a question, what if i'm about to enter a string myself with whatever length.